# How can I manipulate this pandas dataframe with time series data in order to be more easier to use?

Tags: python, pandas, time, series

I have a pandas dataframe with time series data, where the columns are looking like this:

| Customer | Item | Date | 00:00 | 00:30 | 01:00 | ... | 23:30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | A | 2020-01-01 | 0 | 1 | 2 | ... | 3 |
| XYZ | B | 2020-01-02 | 0 | 2 | 2 | ... | 5 |
| ABC | A | 2020-01-01 | 0 | 1 | 5 | ... | 3 |
| ABC | B | 2020-01-02 | 0 | 2 | 2 | ... | 1 |

So the hours are in the columns, instead of the rows. I want to manipulate this dataframe, concatenate the time columns into the date column, and make them a separate rows, like this:

| Customer | Date | Item A | Item B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 2020-01-01 00:00 | 1 | 2 |
| XYZ | 2020-01-01 00:30 | 1 | 2 |
| XYZ | 2020-01-01 01:00 | 1 | 2 |
| XYZ | 2020-01-02 00:00 | 1 | 2 |
| XYZ | 2020-01-02 00:30 | 1 | 2 |
| XYZ | 2020-01-02 01:00 | 1 | 2 |
| ABC | 2020-01-01 00:00 | 2 | 3 |
| ABC | 2020-01-01 00:30 | 2 | 2 |
| ABC | 2020-01-01 01:00 | 4 | 2 |
| ABC | 2020-01-02 00:00 | 2 | 3 |
| ABC | 2020-01-02 00:30 | 2 | 2 |
| ABC | 2020-01-02 01:00 | 4 | 2 |

How can I do this? I tried a method using cross join, but that is very uneffective, because I have  a lot of rows. (~100000)

Comment: Where does the data come from?  If you're reading this from a CSV file, it might be easier to convert it as you read each line, and THEN convert to pandas.

Comment: Yep, it is coming from a CSV file. Hmm, could you show me an example of that reading-convertion? I have never used that.

Comment: It's a "wide to long" transformation. Have you tried `melt` + `pivot`? e.g. `df.melt(id_vars=['Customer', 'Item', 'Date']).reset_index().pivot(index=['index', 'Customer', 'Date', 'variable'], columns='Item', values='value')`

Comment: Come on.  For each line, you add 48 lines to your master list.  At the end, you pass that to `pandas.DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following (with `df` your dataframe):

```py
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = (
    df.rename(columns={"Item": "Items"})
    .melt(id_vars=["Customer", "Items", "Date"], var_name="Time", value_name="Item")
    .assign(Date=lambda df: df["Date"] + pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"] + ":00"))
    .drop(columns="Time")
    .pivot(index=["Customer", "Date"], columns="Items")
    .reset_index()
)
df.columns = [a if not b else f"{a} {b}" for a, b in df.columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the one that I was looking for! I have never use melt, so I didn't know about this method. I learned a lot from this.